# conditionalpanel and boxes width not giving expected output R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am working to build a dashboard using R Shiny.

My UI code is as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = 'Telematics Packages'),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(id = 'menu', 
            menuItem(text = 'Plot', tabName = 'Plots', icon = icon('chart-bar')),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.menu == 'Plots'",
                selectInput('variableselect', 'Select a Variable', choices = names(wide_data)[-c(1,2)]),
                selectInput('UserSelect', 'Select a Vehicle', choices = c('All',unique(wide_data$device_user))),
                dateRangeInput('daterange', 'Enter Start and End Date', start = min(wide_data$SampleTime), end = max(wide_data$SampleTime), min = min(wide_data$SampleTime), max = max(wide_data$SampleTime))
            )
        
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItem(tabName = 'plots',
                fluidRow(width = 12,
                column(width = 8, box(title = "Variable's Distribution",plotOutput('plot'))),
                column(width = 4, box(title = 'Bins Count', sliderInput('binscount', 'Observations', min = 10, value = 30, max = 50)))
                )
    )
)
)
```

Server code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

function(input, output) {

     datafiler <- reactive({
         if(input$UserSelect == 'All')
         {
             filteredData <- wide_data %>% filter(SampleTime == input$daterange)
         } else{
                filteredData <- wide_data %>% filter(device_user == input$UserSelect & SampleTime == input$daterange)
                return(filteredData)
                }
     })
     
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(data = datafiler(), aes(x = .data[[input$variableselect]])) + geom_histogram(bins = input$binscount, color = 'red', fill = 'green', alpha = 0.4)
    })
    
}
```

As can be seen, I've used the conditionalpanel to hide the various inputs to the "Plot" tab, but the inputs are all visible.. I've also used the column width adding to 12. `wide_data` is a dataframe of 250k records. But from the two boxes are placed far apart. Could someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

[image]

structure of data:

```
 $ SampleTime      : POSIXct[1:500], format: "2020-12-01" "2020-12-01" "2020-12-01" "2020-12-01" ...
 $ device_user     : chr [1:500] "B1" "B1" "B1" "B1" ...
 $ ENGINE RPM      : num [1:500] 1520 1760 1720 1500 1910 1740 1270 1670 1420 1320 ...
 $ VEHICLE SPEED   : num [1:500] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ACCELERATION X  : num [1:500] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ACCELERATION Y  : num [1:500] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ACCELERATION Z  : num [1:500] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ EXTERNAL BATTERY: num [1:500] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ IGNTIONSTATUS   : num [1:500] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

sample data:

```
structure(list(SampleTime = structure(c(1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 
1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000, 1606761000
), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), device_user = c("B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1"), `ENGINE RPM` = c(1520, 1760, 1720, 1500, 1910, 1740, 1270, 
1670, 1420, 1320, 1510, 1500, 1280, 1340, 1310, 1300, 1100, 1250, 
1500, 1180, 1060, 1430, 1050, 1250, 1230, 1260, 2220, 1880, 1090, 
2080, 1270, 860, 850, 810, 800, 810, 830, 800, 790, 780, 1680, 
1260, 2020, 1570, 790, 1570, 1310, 1760, 1750, 950, 1720, 1340, 
1400, 1410, 1150, 1220, 1670, 1350, 1310, 780, 1430, 920, 1800, 
1110, 1770, 1610, 970, 1510, 1560, 1240, 1570, 840, 1220, 1380, 
970, 770, 1920, 1280, 830, 1740, 1230, 1170, 1180, 2290, 1380, 
1110, 1970, 1620, 1230, 1270, 1750, 1810, 1740, 800, 1530, 1310, 
1090, 1170, 1410, 790, 860, 2250, 1830, 1880, 920, 790, 760, 
750, 1790, 1470, 1360, 1470, 1340, 1530, 960, 930, 990, 840, 
1200, 1600, 1640, 1490, 850, 2570, 2100, 1330, 780, 850, 760, 
1150, 910, 2180, 1820, 1870, 1860, 1910, 1890, 800, 1550, 1850, 
1710, 2030, 1960, 2120, 2020, 880, 1920, 1890, 2190, 2350, 2060, 
1710, 950, 840, 1010, 1340, 840, 890, 1510, 1320, 1050, 1520, 
830, 1540, 1710, 830, 840, 1150, 1810, 1540, 810, 1400, 1710, 
830, 860, 1070, 770, 1580, 1460, 1300, 820, 1120, 770, 750, 770, 
800, 700, 700, 690, 700, 820, 810, 760, 770, 1470, 760, 780, 
770, 750, 1120), `VEHICLE SPEED` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `ACCELERATION X` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `ACCELERATION Y` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `ACCELERATION Z` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `EXTERNAL BATTERY` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), IGNTIONSTATUS = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're trying to do here. Just get the plot and bin counter close to each other?

Comment: @TTS, yes and also, the conditionalpanel doesn't seem to hide the inputs for the tab "Plot"

Comment: Two things I notice right off - first, I don't believe `fluidRow` has any `width`. Second, your tabNames don't match - "Plots" vs. "plots"

Comment: @TTS, it doesn't make any difference, the output plot is just the same.

Comment: Your first menuItem is active when it starts.  If you have a Home menuItem as your first menuItem, then the second menuItem will have the conditionalPanel items, and they will not be displayed until you select the Plots menuItem.

Comment: @YBS, so If I have only one menuItem, the inputs will be displayed always. The concept of conditionalPanel applies only for the menuItems that come after the first menuItem?

Comment: Your conditionalPanel is working as it is picking the active menuItem.  In case of one menuItem, there is no need of conditionalPanel.  Instead use menuSubItem.

Comment: If you add another `menuItem` you can test whether or not your `conditionalPanel` is appearing only when the correct tab is selected.  In your example, the inputs should *always* be showing, because it always has the one tab selected (only choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `conditionalPanel` is working as intended.  As for the plot not filling the container properly, it's actually because of the `box`.  If you look at `?box` it has a default `width=6`, which would make it take up half of `column(width=8,...)`.  So if you simply adjust...

```
dashboardBody(
    tabItem(tabName = 'Plots',
            fluidRow(
                     column(width = 8, box(width = 12, title = "Variable's Distribution", plotOutput('plot'))),
```

...your plot and bins select should be next to each other as desired.  You can also adjust  `height` for the plot.

Comment: Thanks, will accept the answer, BTW, for the plotOutput I entered height = 250, then the sliderinput overlapped with the histogram, before I placed the sliderinput next to the plot. Could you please let me know how to address the issue in the future.

Comment: Sizing things properly is often a testing process.  It might take a few tries to get it right, but it would be helpful to remember all the 'containers' present:  'plotOutput', 'box', 'column'. Your `plot` has height/width properties with default values.  That plot lives inside a `box` which also has height/width properties. That `box` lives inside a `column`, which has a width.